# Limiting Population Size while Hatching Additional Turtles

Tags: netlogo

I have a slider that controls population, set to the max value of 100, which creates 100 turtles in the nest. However, the number of turtles within a breed is independent of the total population, so instead of having 100 total turtles, I get 100 + #breed1 + #breed2. Additionally, I am hatching new turtles of breed [followers] and [foragers] during the course of the model. How do I get the turtles to die each time a new breed member is hatched?
I know this is not a code problem, but ideally, I would like the new foragers to be the turtles that are in the nest, not just new turtles.

`````````
to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "bug"
  create-turtles population
  create-foragers 10
  [set color yellow]
end

to go  ;; forever button
  ask leaders
  [wiggle
    fd 1
    return-to-nest]
  ask followers
  [if any? leaders
    [uphill-chemical
      fd 3
      pickup-food]
    uphill-food
    fd 1
    if distancexy nest-x nest-y < 3 and color = violet 
    [hatch-foragers 1
      [set color yellow
       uphill-chemical]]
  tick
end

to return-to-nest  ;; turtle procedure
ifelse nest?
  [if count followers < 5
    [hatch-followers 1 [set color brown - 1]]
  facexy food-x food-y  ;; drop food and head out again
  move-to patch food-x food-y]
[else commands]
end
````````
`````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to maintain a population is simply to ask a newly born turtle to kill a randomly selected turtle. So instead of:

```
[ if count followers < 5
  [ hatch-followers 1
    [ set color brown - 1
    ]
  ]
```

you could have:

```
[ if count followers < 5
  [ hatch-followers 1
    [ set color brown - 1
      ask one-of turtles [die]
    ]
  ]
```